# Unable to disable Jquery UI datepicker in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, angular-schema-form

I am using Jquery UI datepicker in my angular app, also for rendering the all form controls including datepicker, I am using plugin [Angular Schema-Form](http://schemaform.io/). To add Jquery UI datepicker in it, I created my own custom [decorator](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/extending.md#defining-a-decorator)

Now when I disable the datepicker (depending on the model value), clinking on the calendar icon doesn't open the calendar pop up. This works fine in Chrome and FF but in IE even though the datepicker is disabled clicking on the icon opens the pop up.

**Custom Decorator Directive:**

```
<input ng-show="form.key"
                   type="datepicker" exc-datepicker
                   step="any"
                   sf-changed="form"
                   placeholder="{{form.placeholder}}"
                   class="exc-datepicker form-control {{form.fieldHtmlClass}}"
                   id="{{form.key.slice(-1)[0]}}"
                   ng-model-options="form.ngModelOptions"
                   ng-model="$$value$$"
                   ng-disabled="form.readonly || evalExpr(form.ngDisabled)"
                   schema-validate="form"
                   name="{{form.key.slice(-1)[0]}}"
                   aria-describedby="{{form.key.slice(-1)[0] + 'Status'}}"
                   ui-mask="{{form.mask}}" ui-mask-model-view-value="{{form.maskIncluded || false}}"
                   date-options="form.dateOptions"
                   exc-compare="form.compare"
                   readonly>
```

**Decorator:**

```
decoratorsProvider.defineDecorator('myDecoratorSimple', {
    'datepicker': {
        template: base + 'datepicker.html',
        replace: false
    },
}, []);
```

**Schema:**

```
schema = {
       type: "object",
       properties: {
           ServiceInformation: {
               type: "object",
               required: ["StartServiceDate"],
               properties: {
                   StartServiceDate: { title: "Start Service Date", type: "string", format: "string" },

               }
           }
       }
};
```

**Form:**

```
form = [{
    tyep: "datepicker",
    key: "ServiceInformation.StartServiceDate",
    feedback: false,
    maskIncluded: true,
    mask: "19/39/2999",
    placeholder: "  /  /    ",
    fieldHtmlClass: "exc-datepicker",
    dateOptions: {
        beforeShowDay: "startServiceDatePickerFilter",
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    },
    ngModelOptions: {
        allowInvalid: "true"
    },
}];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you replicate a small example in Plunker?